# Design Json with limitation of 32kb

Tags: json, design-patterns, architecture

we are rolling out our product in versions. Every product version will have unique features and be supported by a variety of states.

Design must be able to toggle between many features, products, and states.

After considering several options, it was decided to put this in a Json file and generate a flag. We then used a program internally to read the flag, but this tool has a 32kb Json file size restriction.

How can we create a flag with this restriction in mind to achieve feature, product and state level control?

Tried the below options it works but the we are hitting with the json limitation.

should we split single flag in to multiple flags ? what options are available?

```
{
    "Version" :"4.1",
     "Features" :
     [
         {
             "Feature": "A",
             "SupportedStates" : "AZ,TX,IL,"
         },
         {
             "Feature": "B",
             "SupportedStates" : "AZ,TX,IL,"
         },
         {
             "Feature": "C",
             "SupportedStates" : "AZ,TX,IL,HI,AK,DD,HH,TT,EE,RR,"
         }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about what is a "flag" and where it should be expressed? I can't see it in the example that you provided and it's not completely clear how it should be used.

Comment: I would suggest to use another solution for reading and processing the json files, that does not have a size limitation. There is no technical reason to limit the file size.